# Performance issue with Pressable in React Native with android

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, performance, react-navigation

I noticed some performance-related issues on my React native app (Android Version) while using the React native API (Pressable). When pressed, it lags for some seconds before it responds especially when using it to navigate between screens. I don't seem to know why this is happening. It works perfectly on IOS.

I upgraded my React Native version to 0.71.2. I expected this to fix the lag but it did not

Comment: Could you share your code with and without the performance issue?

Comment: Obviously, the main cause of lag is extra re-renders, not using a component. You must share your codes or prepare a snack expo, then we can test your issue. Have you tested your issue by using another Touchable component? If still the lag happens then the cause isn't Pressable.

Comment: Are you using "createStackNavigator" from react-navigation? If you are using it then replace it with "createNativeStackNavigator"

Comment: What is the reason for replacing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am sure the `Pressable` causes laggy more than other `TouchableComponent`, please see the code here:

Compare [`TouchableOpacity`](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/9b8ffeee4c54eb05ca74d626b171a958fa6db4d4/Libraries/Components/Touchable/TouchableOpacity.js) with [`Pressability`](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/9b8ffeee4c54eb05ca74d626b171a958fa6db4d4/Libraries/Pressability/Pressability.js)

You can see `Pressable` is a heavy component, it holds more events, even it's own `Gesture`, hence I suggest to do not using `Pressable` many times, such as in the FlatList item...

Comment: How are you sure the cause of the lag is `Pressable`?

Comment: I have a ChatApp with many Pressable component inside, move to TouableOpacity then I see the fps better, before I search many issues, most of theme decided to not use Pressable many times, such as react-native-elements does not use it

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar issue in my project, and I found a solution that worked for me. I was using `createStackNavigator` from react-navigation, and I was experiencing lag on Android. After replacing it with `createNativeStackNavigator`, the performance issue was resolved. It might be worth trying out in your project as well. Good luck!

Comment: Oh. I will try this. Thank you

Comment: This didn’t work for me.

Answer (score 0):

React Native provides `InteractionManager` to handle long-running tasks and improve responsiveness. You can wrap your navigation code in `InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions` to ensure it runs smoothly without blocking the UI thread.

```js
import { InteractionManager } from 'react-native';

InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions(() => {
  // Your navigation code here
});
```